# Get Current User ID in CloudKit?

Tags: cloudkit

How do I get the current UserId of user? I'm using the following code:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
                   self.currentuserID = userID?.userRecordID
                    print("user record id")
                    print(userID)

                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
```

However at the end currentUserID is set to nill? Does anyone know how to successfully gain permission and get the current user id?

Comment: Have you checked for an error before the subsequent fetch and discover call?  Where are you running this code?  Are you signed into iCloud on the device?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you don't need permission from `requestApplicationPermission` to get the CloudKit user's unique ID. You can do this...

```
CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID() { recordID, error in
  //...
}
```

Without ever calling this...

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability){ status, error in
  //...
}
```

The `.userDiscoverability` is just so other app users can locate your unique user record through an email or phone number.

I hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `status` value before fetch user information. It could be something like this...

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
    switch status
    {
        case .granted:
            print("iCloud is OK")

        case .initialState:
            print("The user has not yet decided whether to grant this permission")
            return

        case .couldNotComplete:
            print("An error occurred during the getting or setting of the app permission")

            if let error = error
            {
                print("err @ \(#function) -> \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            return

        case .denied:
            print("The user denied access to the permission.")
            return
    }

    CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) 
        {
            CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
               self.currentuserID = userID?.userRecordID
                print("user record id")
                print(userID)

            })
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```